# logback if else condition not setting property

Tags: java, logback

I'm trying to set a property in logback config file based on the value of a System property.

My logback.xml has the following:

```
<configuration>
  <property name="env" value="${env}" />

  <if condition='property("env").equals("prod")'>
    <then>
      <property name="myProperty" value="PRODUCTION"/>
    </then>
    <else>
      <property name="myProperty" value="DEVELOPMENT"/>
    </else>
  </if>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern> env=${myProperty} msg=%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I run my java code with and without the system property `-Denv=prod`

Java code:

```
System.out.println("System property env=" + System.getProperty("env"));
log.info("This is a test.");
```

Outputs:

```
System property env=prod
env=myProperty_IS_UNDEFINED msg=This is a test.
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting `myProperty_IS_UNDEFINED`?

Comment: How are you running your java code?

Answer (score -1):

It's because its defined inside the if/else block. Try to add one additional line before if/else block.

```
<property name="myProperty" value=""/>
```

Comment: -1; it's possible I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure this is just incorrect. Conditionally defining properties works for me without needing a `<property>` element outside the `<if ...>`.